# PHP wrong result with pow(11, 23)

Tags: php, math, pow

I have a problem with pow(11, 23). The PHP result is 895430243255237361008640.
According to this german encrypt tutorial (page 5)
http://www.dkruse.de/dokumente/netzwerke/Sicher3_Asymm_Verschluesselung.pdf
the result should be 895430243255237372246531.

Also when I calculate 895430243255237372246531 % 187, the result is 126.
It should be 88, according to the tutorial. I use PHP Version 7.3.11.

I would be happy for any help

Comment: It sounds like this number might be bigger than `PHP_INT_MAX`. Could you echo that constant and check?

Comment: you many need the php BCMath  library https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of PHP_INT_MAX and just tested bcpowmod(). This works! Best Regards

Comment: @ACJ no , when i did var_dump(pow(11, 23)) it returnd float

Comment: So is there any similar limit for float as well>?

Comment: @SandrinJoy, php handling a number as a floating point is actually indication that it is larger than `PHP_INT_MAX`. Which is why I suggested echoing that (`PHP_INT_MAX`, that is).

Comment: @SandrinJoy It's because the number is represented as `8.9543024325524E+23`. Note the exponent `E+23` at the end, because the number is so large.

Comment: @SandrinJoy, yes, `PHP_FLOAT_MAX` also exists, but that wouldn’t be very useful in the context of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

php does not calculate that exactly. I did the math and just got the same result as you did. This document was created 2011 on a mac computer. Maybe there was an issue with PHP 5 or there is a difference between x64 and x32 architecture but idk

Comment: Integer calculations are exact as long as the numbers involved are between `PHP_INT_MIN` and `PHP_INT_MAX`. The values of these constants indeed depend on the architecture.